# Is it possible to execute PHP code when I specify and not when the page is loaded

Tags: php, javascript, html

This is my code(form).

```
<tr>
<td class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color=#00000 />Content Type</td>
<td colspan=""><input id="type" type="radio" name="content_type" value='article' onclick="check_type()">Article </input> 
<input id="type" type="radio" name="content_type" value='image' onclick="check_type()">Image </input>
<input id="type" type="radio" name="content_type" value='url' onclick="check_type()">Url </input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="" class="">&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color=#00000 />Select Asset</td>
<td width="" colspan=""><select disabled="disabled" id="asset" name="content_asset">
<option value='create_new_content'>select asset</option>
    <?php
    $dir='../Assets/10/';
    if($handle = opendir($dir)){
      while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){
    if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != "Thumbs.db"){
     $extension = explode('.',$file);
     if($extension[1] == 'png' || $extension[1] == 'gif' || $extension[1] == 'jpg'){
       echo "<option value=".$file.">".$file."</option>";
    }
      }
    }
    closedir($handle);
  }
 ?>
</select></td>
</tr>
```

Is it possible to execute the PHP code when the radio button is clicked. I enable the drop down box using javascript when the radio button is clicked.

Answer (score 4):

You would have to put the php code to execute on another page and call it with AJAX.

EDIT: [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) has a neat way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is executed on the server side, I'm not sure but I suspect that precludes it re-rendering anything without a page reload. I think JavaScript might help!

Edit: in fact, it looks like the related threads off to the right there are exactly the sort of information you'd want.

Answer (score 0):

use ajax for load your php on an event

Answer (score 0):

NO, because the PHP code is already executed when you load this form on browser.

It would be better if you create three different dropdown for Article, Image and URL each and keep them hidden, and based on selection of radio button show relative dropdown.

Looks like you are re-factoring/patching the code so I would not suggest you jQuery or some other option.

ATB